# preg_replace with wildcards?

Tags: php, regex

I have HTML markup bearing the form

<div id='abcd1234A'><p id='wxyz1234A'>Hello</p></div>

which I need to replace to bear the form

<div id='abcd1234AN'><p id='wxyz1234AN'>Hello</p></div>

where N may be 1,2.. .

The best I have been able to do is as follows

```
function cloneIt($a,$b)
{
 return substr_replace($a,$b,-1);
}

$ndx = "1'";
$str = "<div id='abcd1234A'><p id='wxyz1234A'>Hello</p></div>";
preg_match_all("/id='[a-z]{4}[0-9]{4}A'/",$str,$matches);

$matches = $matches[0];
$reps = array_merge($matches);
$ndxs = array_fill(0,count($reps),$ndx);
$reps = array_map("cloneIt",$reps,$ndxs);

$str = str_replace($matches,$reps,$str);
echo htmlspecialchars($str);
```

which works just fine.  However, my REGEX skills are not much to write home about so I suspect that there is probably a better way to do this.  I'd be most obliged to anyone who might be able to suggest a neater/quicker way of accomplishing the same result.

Comment: I'm not sure how this HTML is designed for duplication.  Are you generating these nested tags in a loop and the `$ndx` is incremented? Do you have full control of the `$str`?  If you are modifying a static string that you are hardcoding, then `preg_replace()` will be fine (although I am a big proponent of DOM parsers).  Match the id values and end the pattern with `\K`, then add your `$ndx` as the replacement.

Answer (score 1):

You can optimize your regex like this:

```
/id='[a-z]{4}\d{4}A'/
```

#### Sample code

```
preg_match_all("/id='[a-z]{4}\\d{4}A'/",$str,$matches);
```

However an alternative would consist in using en HTML parser. Here I'll use [simple html dom](http://simplehtmldom.sourceforge.net/):

```
// Load the HTML from URL or file
$html = file_get_html('http://www.mysite.com/');
// You can also load $html from string: $html = str_get_html($my_string);


// Find div with id attribute
foreach($html->find('div[id]') as $div) {
    if (preg_match("/id='([a-z]{4}\\d{4})A'/" , $div->id, $matches)) {
       $div->id = $matches[1] + $ndx;
    } 
}

echo $html->save();
```

Did you notice how **elegant**, **concise** and **clear** the code becomes with an *html parser* ?

#### References

- [Simple Html Dom Documentation](http://simplehtmldom.sourceforge.net/manual.htm)

Comment: I have used simplehtmldom but in this instance I suspect its use would be inappropriate.  I only have to deal with short snippets of HTML (a handful of nested elements at a time) not a full document. The elegance of the code would probably come at the expense of speed.  When I posted the question I was thinking more along the lines of - surely there is a way to do this with regex lookaheads or something (which are way beyond my limited regex capabilities).

Comment: @DroidOS You can load your html snippets from string with `str_get_html`.

Comment: @DroidOS *The elegance of the code would probably come at the expense of speed* Don't make assumption, measure the code speed first !